Can a Guru(bad guru) be rejected?
Can a Guru be rejected..especially if he preaches wrong philosophy?
Kindly mention as many scriptural references as possible.Thanks

yes, a disciple has the right to select the right guru.

As per Vaishnavism, yes https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Unqualified_guru_means_who_does_not_know_how_to_guide_the_disciple._Guru%27s_duty_is_to_guide._So_such_kind_of_guru_can_be_at_least_rejected

This question is similar to: What if Guru's order is contrary to scriptures should it still be followed?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
